# How to get Scroll event and count the number of scroll events

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append data to html table when the user scrolls down to the end of the page, which i am able to do. But how do I keep the count of scroll downs?? At each instance I need the count to be added by one, each time my url will be appended by that count.. and when the count reaches 6, i should stop appending the count to the urls..
Please share some thought on how to approach that...

[test file](http://jsfiddle.net/Sullan/sk5yc/1/) is added here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var count = 1;  
jQuery("#scrollPane").scroll(function() {
    if (Math.ceil(boxHeight - $inner.offset().top + boxOffsetTop) >= innerOuterHeight ) {
    if(count==6)
    {
        alert("stop");
    }
    count++;

}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sk5yc/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot a lot it worked fine for me.... But with one problem..
I am appending data from the server to the table, on success the scroll goes to middle position, and even before i pull the scroller to the bottom, the next ajax request is triggerd.. i guess the height calculation changes when the data is appended to the table.. how do i fix this..Updated sample can be seen here

http://jsfiddle.net/sk5yc/10/

Comment: Check this one out http://jsfiddle.net/sk5yc/11/ all your varidable declarations were outside the scroll function so the height won't change even after the new data is appended. So i shifted them into inside the scroll function take a look

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works like a charm... now I can sleep in peace.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 1;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
        alert(counter + " scroll me again");
        counter++;
        if (counter > 6) {
            $(this).unbind('scroll');
            alert('no more scrolling')
        }
    }
});
```

-10 indicates how far away from end of page user must be before function executes. This gives you the flexibility to adjust the behavior as needed.

When count reaches 6, it will unbind the scroll. So the feature is turned off.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/wQfMx/3/

Answer (score 1):

Tracking the scroll like this will probably cause you problems.

I have written an article which tracks scroll depth and reports information back to Google Analytics.

In my development I discovered that the scroll event is fired many times, a lot more than I expected. It tracking a count would be very unpredictable. I think it would probably be better to track if you are 90% scrolled down the document. However you also need to have a trigger mechanism to stop processing events until you are ready to process more or you will end up making a series of load content calls in quick succession.

The following code is triggered when you reach 90% scroll depth for the document. It then locks itself and doesn't fire the event any more. After you have loaded your content you could reset the IsDuplicateScrollEvent back to 0 and the scroll load trigger would work again.

```
<script src='http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var IsDuplicateScrollEvent = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        TrackEventsForPageScroll();
    });


    function TrackEventsForPageScroll()
    {
       $(window).scroll(function(){
         var scrollPercent = GetScrollPercent();

         if(scrollPercent > 90)
         {
           if(IsDuplicateScrollEvent == 0)
           { 
             IsDuplicateScrollEvent = 1;
             alert("Page Scrolled to 90% in " + document.location.href);
             // trigger your content load here
           }
         }
       }); 
    }

    function GetScrollPercent()
    {
         var bottom = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
         var height = $(document).height();

         return Math.round(100*bottom/height);
    } 
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

This code is taken from my article at:

- http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2011/04/tracking-scroll-depth-to-reveal-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying an 'infinite scroll'? If that's the case, there are already some jquery plugins for that like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/scrollLoad

There are also tutorial for this like http://ajaxian.com/archives/implementing-infinite-scrolling-with-jquery